# Change text input for Open ID manual entry to be lower case

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, mobile-web

This is a purely cosmetic request, but the manual OpenID entry screen is repetitive, not as clear as it could be, and uses an initial capital where lower case seems more appropriate.

Also, if you want someone to enter the URL the title at the top says OpenID Login (cancel) and the Main text says "Log in with any OpenID." and the hint shows "Enter your OpenId".

1. Please harmonize the spelling of OpenID (either capitalize or keep lower the final D but it should be consistent) among the three uses of that word on the page
2. Consider making the hint **http://example.com** since that's what will be entered there
3. Change the "Log in with any OpenID" to read "Enter the URL for your OpenID provider/server" or something that doesn't just repeat the title
4. Change the text field to be lower case instead of sentence case (first h of http gets capitalized and it could be lower case by default)
5. The screen before the manual entry scene also has OpenID spelled OpenId

Comment: OpenID branding is uppercase. One big OpenID provider is MyOpenId, which has mixed case. (MyOpenId were supposed to shut down on the 1st of Feb, but seem to be still going strong. I use them, but have a few alternative logins lined up in case they actually do go down at some stage.)

Answer (score 2):

This will be updated soon in a build near you.